# Upload of a big file (>3mb) from Valum's ajax upload to Rails fails without calling controler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I'm trying to upload pics with valums' against a ruby server apache & nginx + passenger , rails 3 ruby 1.9 (1.8 on dev)
Typically a file over 3Mb will fail with the following trace :

### #

Started POST "/settings/uploadpict?qqfile=venise.JPG&user_id=680251975" for 82.245.125.231 at Tue Apr 05 23:30:30 +0200 2011

TypeError (expected Hash (got String) for param `'):

Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (17.2ms)

### #

I made sure it's not apache or nginx cutting the flow (nginx did that and I raised to max sie of a request)

What's puzzling is that my controller is not even called (it starts with a logger.console which does not print... ) so I'm a bit helpless to trace the issue...

Any clue ?

view code  (controller is never called ...)

```
//Valum's Ajax File Upload //
function setup_file_upload(){
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
// pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
element: $("#settings_upload_btn")[0],
// path to server-side upload script
  action: '/settings/uploadpict',
// additional data to send, name-value pairs
params: {
    user_id: <%=@user.fb_id%>
},
// validation    
// ex. ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'] or []
allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'gif', 'bmp'],        
// each file size limit in bytes
// this option isn't supported in all browsers
//sizeLimit: 0, // max size   
//minSizeLimit: 0, // min size

// set to true to output server response to console
debug: false,

// events         
// you can return false to abort submit
onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
    //clean-up the mess....
    $(".qq-upload-list").empty();
},
onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total){},
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
    if (responseJSON["success"] == "false" || responseJSON["success"] == undefined) {
        $(".qq-upload-failed-text").show();
    }else{
        //do the dance
        uploadDone(responseJSON["filename"]);   
    }



},
onCancel: function(id, fileName){},

messages: {
    // error messages, see qq.FileUploaderBasic for content            
},
showMessage: function(message){ alert(message); }
});
}
```

Comment: Might be useful to see your view code and/or controller

Comment: added that to main - controller is useless it's never called ! (that's the whole pain .. a bug in my code I can handle but I can't point out where this error is being thrown from...)

Answer (score 0):

After investigation I found a workaround => DESACTIVATE XHR !!!

in valums's fileuploader .js:

```
qq.UploadHandlerXhr.isSupported = function(){
return false;    
};
```

and after that it works flawlessly using legacy iframe ... no more nice progressbar though...

Answer (score 0):

found this here http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/116980/iphone--rails--xhr--undefined-method-tosym-for-nilnilclass

I found the "problem", it's in the Rails source code

The error is in rails/actionpack-3.0.3/instrumentation.rb line (22)

I don't know if it is real a problem. It occurs because Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient() doesn't send the Content-Type as default
In my example, I wasn't used a Content-Type, it's causing error on rails
I added Content-Type in the code
    //...
    xhr.open('GET', url, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send();
    ///
Now it works
I think that text/plain can be the default Content-Type for Titanium XHR, not empty like now. I also created a ticket on Rails Issue Tracker https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6546-error-sending-empty-content-type-instrumentationrb22